# Creating ListenerPort in WebSphere using Java code

Tags: java, websphere

I am trying to create Listener port in Java using the `ConfigService`. I had created listener port created in Jysthon similarly in AdminConfig.create. When I try that in Java with type `ListenerPort`. I am getting invalid attribute name/type. Any idea why?

I tried the below Java code. Here `messageListenerService` is of type `objectName` which represents the message listener service that I obtained from the server using the `queryObject`.

```
configService.createConfigData(session, messageListenerService, "ListenerPort", "ListenerPort", attributeList)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using listenerPorts for the attribute name solve the issue.